# Pandas Dataframe Question Probably Pivot but not sure

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pivot, transpose

I've been working on this for a few hours, and continue to struggle.  I have a dataframe (df) that looks like this:

| Job Number | Timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| 124356 | 07/06/2023 09:00:00 |
| 124356 | 07/06/2023 10:00:00 |
| 124356 | 07/06/2023 11:00:00 |
| 124356 | 07/06/2023 12:00:00 |
| 654321 | 07/06/2023 13:00:00 |
| 654321 | 07/06/2023 14:00:00 |

I'm trying to generate a secondary dataframe (df2), the end result which looks like this:

| Job Number | In | Out | In | Out |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | 07/06/2023 09:00:00 | 07/06/2023 10:00:00 | 07/06/2023 11:00:00 | 07/06/2023 12:00:00 |
| 654321 | 07/06/2023 13:00:00 | 07/06/2023 14:00:00 |  |  |

I've tried these two commands:

/* Pivot the dataframe on Job Name */

df2 = df.pivot(index="Job Name", columns="Timestamp", values="Timestamp").reset_index()

/* Make the result be left justified */

df2 = df2.T.apply(lambda x : sorted(x,key=pd.isnull)).T

but the end result looks like this:

| Job Number | 07/06/2023 09:00:00 | 07/06/2023 10:00:00 | 07/06/2023 11:00:00 | 07/06/2023 12:00:00 | 07/06/2023 13:00:00 | 07/06/2023 14:00:00 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | 07/06/2023 09:00:00 | 07/06/2023 10:00:00 | 07/06/2023 11:00:00 | 07/06/2023 12:00:00 |  |  |
| 654321 | 07/06/2023 13:00:00 | 07/06/2023 14:00:00 |  |  |  |  |

So, it's adding two more columns than it needs to, likely because there are 6 total timestamps.  The issue I'm having is that in actuality I'm going to have a variable number of these timestamps.
They could easily number in the thousands, but not for every job.  As a result, I don't want to create a boatload of columns unnecessarily.

Any suggestions on how to overcome this, and also, any tips on renaming every other column (except the left most one) In/Out/In/Out/etc.?

Thank you in advance for any assistance,

Clare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first assign alternating In/Out with a [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumcount.html)+[`mod`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mod.html), then [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
(df.assign(n=df.groupby('Job Number').cumcount(),
           col=lambda d: np.where(d['n'].mod(2)==0, 'In', 'Out'))
   .pivot(index='Job Number', columns=['col', 'n'], values='Timestamp')
   .droplevel(1, axis=1).rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index()
)
```

Alternative with [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) and the modulo operator (`%`):

```
(df.assign(n=df.groupby('Job Number').cumcount())
   .pivot(index='Job Number', columns='n', values='Timestamp')
   .rename(columns=lambda x: ['In', 'Out'][x%2])
   .rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index() # optional
)
```

*NB. this assumes the dates are initially sorted.*

Output:

```
   Job Number                   In                  Out                   In                  Out
0      124356  07/06/2023 09:00:00  07/06/2023 10:00:00  07/06/2023 11:00:00  07/06/2023 12:00:00
1      654321  07/06/2023 13:00:00  07/06/2023 14:00:00                  NaN                  NaN
```

Reproducible input:

```
from pandas import Timestamp
df = pd.DataFrame({'Job Number': [123456, 123456, 123456, 123456, 654321, 654321],
                   'Timestamp': [Timestamp('2023-07-06 09:00:00'), Timestamp('2023-07-06 10:00:00'), Timestamp('2023-07-06 11:00:00'), Timestamp('2023-07-06 12:00:00'), Timestamp('2023-07-06 13:00:00'), Timestamp('2023-07-06 14:00:00')]})
```

Comment: Hi @mozway,  Thank you so much for taking the time to look at this and help me out.  It is true the dates are in fact initially sorted, by Job Number that is.  Unfortunately for me, when I run the code you suggested, I'm encountering this error:  KeyError: 'Level col not found'    It seems you were able to correctly generate the EXACT output I'm hoping for.  Hmmm.... any ideas why it's not compiling for me?

Comment: Please provide your input in a reproducible format, there might be a minor difference

Comment: Hello, The input is being read in from an Excel spreadsheet into a dataframe called df.  It matches exactly the dataframe shown at the very top of my question.  Two columns, one labeled Job Number, the other labeled Timestamp, with the exact values shown in that table above.  I'm sorry, I wish I could attached the Excel spreadsheet, but I don't seem to be allowed to do so.

Comment: Provide the output of `df.to_dict('tight')`

Comment: This is what I'm seeing when I run that...

Program Running.... please standby
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/.../main.py", line 30, in <module>
    df.to_dict('tight')
  File "C:\Users\..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1439, in to_dict
    raise ValueError(f"orient '{orient}' not understood")
ValueError: orient 'tight' not understood

Comment: Then just `df.to_dict()`, which pandas version do you have?

Comment: The Pandas version I'm running is 2.0.3.  Here's the output to df.to_dict().  Thanks again for all your help.  I really appreciate it.  You're very kind.  


{'Job Number': {0: 123456, 1: 123456, 2: 123456, 3: 123456, 4: 654321, 5: 654321}, 'Timestamp': {0: Timestamp('2023-07-06 09:00:00'), 1: Timestamp('2023-07-06 10:00:00'), 2: Timestamp('2023-07-06 11:00:00'), 3: Timestamp('2023-07-06 12:00:00'), 4: Timestamp('2023-07-06 13:00:00'), 5: Timestamp('2023-07-06 14:00:00')}}

Comment: I tested with your input and this works well, are you sure you're using the latest code in my answer?

Comment: I'm using this code here, which I believe is the latest:  

(df.assign(n=df.groupby('Job Number').cumcount(),
           col=lambda d: np.where(d['n'].mod(2)==0, 'In', 'Out'))
   .pivot(index='Job Number', columns=['col', 'n'], values='Timestamp')
   .droplevel(1, axis=1).rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index()
)

This is the output...

Program Running.... please standby
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\********\...\multi.py", line 1295, in _get_level_number
    level = self.names.index(level)
ValueError: 'col' is not in list.....

Comment: Works fine for me, can you comment the pivot and droplevel lines? Do you still have an error? Then uncomment the droplevel

Comment: With both commented out, it works fine.  When I then uncomment out the droplevel line, the result is:  IndexError: Too many levels: Index has only 1 level, not 2

Comment: Doesn't really make sense and I can't reproduce it, I also provided an alternative, give it a try.

Comment: Wow @mozway.  THANK YOU so much for hanging in there with me.  You are a true scholar and gentleman.  The alternative worked like a CHARM!!!  I truly appreciate all your help, and for going back-and-forth with me on this.  Not sure why the first solution didn't work, but probably a different compiler version or something.  

Thanks again.  I wish there was some way I could repay you.  I am sincerely grateful.

Comment: You're very welcome. There is no compiler in python so I have no clue. I tested on pandas 2.0.1, I doubt there is a big difference with 2.0.3, but I'll give it a try later. Could be a bug…

Comment: Guess what?  When I used Pandas Version 2.0.1 the original solution works.  Throws the error when using Pandas 2.0.3..... ugh....

Comment: Damn, I'll investigate then, thanks for checking ;)

Comment: Okay, so get this.  Here's the sequence of events... was using 2.0.3, and getting errors.  Downgraded to 2.0.1, and it ran perfectly.  Then, upgraded back to 2.0.3, and now it's working.  Honestly, I have no idea.  However, I am very appreciative of you, and very in AWE of your technical skills and abilities.  Thanks again.  You truly helped out a total stranger, and that is so wonderful of you.  Wishing you the VERY BEST!